# How to mark new row as dirty in kendo grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am adding a new row to my grid on a button click event and the code is

```
function AddNewRowToGrid(gridID) {
    var grid = $(gridID).data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.insert(0, { AreaID: -1, AreaName: "New Area", Catalog: 2 });
}
```

and every time I add a new record I need to set it as dirty and if possible as new, and am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add .set("dirtyFields",{AreaID:true}) after insert

```js
function AddNewRowToGrid(gridID) {
    var grid = $(gridID).data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.insert(0, { AreaID: -1, AreaName: "New Area", Catalog: 2}).set("dirtyFields",{AreaID:true});
}
```